# Switching to binocular mode in Google VR for Android?

Tags: android, google-vr

I'm developing a VR App using Google VR for Android.
When I switch to Binocular mode (clicking the headset button), appears the following screen:

[image: Cardboard instructions]

How can I avoid this screen?

It is possible switch to binocular mode programmatically?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday I was working to achieve the same result as you are seeking now. So, I made a workaround for this, I don't know whether its perfect or not but its working at my end.

All you need to do is to get all the child views of the VrVideoView, so that you can customize accordingly.

```
VrVideoView videoWidgetView = (VrVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
View framelayout = ((ViewGroup) videoWidgetView).getChildAt(0);
ArrayList<View> list = getAllChildren(framelayout);

for(final View view : list) {

  if(view.getId() == R.id.transition_frame){
    //set visiblity gone for that cardboard information screen
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

  }
  else if(view.getId() == R.id.transition_icon){
  //perform click action of the same screen's icon which can
  //redirect you to cardboard vr screen directly(binocular mode)
    view.performClick();

  }
}
```

Recursive method to get all the child views :

```
private ArrayList<View> getAllChildren(View v) {

if (!(v instanceof ViewGroup)) {
  ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
  viewArrayList.add(v);
  return viewArrayList;
}

ArrayList<View> result = new ArrayList<View>();

ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {

  View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);

  ArrayList<View> viewArrayList = new ArrayList<View>();
  viewArrayList.add(v);
  viewArrayList.addAll(getAllChildren(child));
  result.addAll(viewArrayList);
}
return result;
}
```

I hope this might solve your problem. Additionally you can direct jump in to fullscreen mode as well by calling respective views.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setTransitionViewEnabled(boolean enabled): https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/GvrView.html#setTransitionViewEnabled(boolean)

For switching between mono and vr mode, setVRModeEnabled(boolean enabled): https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/GvrView.html#setVRModeEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Hi @Isaac, thanks for your answer, I'm using **VrVideoView** there is a way to get a **GvrView** from **VrVideoView**?